# Install multiple packages in R with dependencies and offline

Tags: r, package

For me to install a package A in R I need another 64 packages (these packages depend on each other). I downloaded all the packages in a folder, including package A (I did this on a computer with internet access). I tried the following:

```
library(tools)
write_PACKAGES("/home/user/Documents/packages to install/")
```

after,

```
install.packages ("StarBioTrek", contriburl = "file: /// home / user / Documents / packages to install /", verbose = "progress report")
```

but the following message appeared to me:

```
Error in install.packages: error reading from connection
```

How can I install Package A on another computer (without internet access)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the tarball named StarBioTrek?

Comment: the name is StarBioTrek_1.8.5.tar.gz

Comment: You should use that exact name as far as I remember(I've only done offline installs once and remember it needed the exact name)

Comment: Yes, and you'll also need `repos = NULL` for a local install.

Comment: i tried this:  install.packages("StarBioTrek_1.8.5", contriburl="file:///home/user/Documentos/paquetes_para_instalar/",verbose = "progress report",repos = NULL)   and install.packages("StarBioTrek", contriburl="file:///home/user/Documentos/paquetes_para_instalar/",verbose = "progress report",repos = NULL) and got this in both cases: Error in install.packages: argument not interpetable as logical

Comment: I install my package on an offline computer with the following command and it works fine: `install.packages("Z:/mypackage_0.1.8.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type="source")`.